okular: how to change application for specific file format
I recently updated to fedora 40. Now okular comes in version 24.05.2
I use a pdf document which contains links to local JPG files. In older versions, I clicked on the link and a new application ( eye of gnome ) was opened for the picture.
Now, okular opens the link in a new tab. How can I change that behaviour?
I already found that it starts a new window, but I am not able to open in a different application, which is very bad!
